# Complicated merge based on start and end date pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Assume that I have the following table

```
import pandas as pd, datetime

table = [[datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 27), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 31), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 1), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 3), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 15), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 28), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 17), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 28), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 12), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 28), 1]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Date', 'Id'])
df2 = df1.copy()
df2['Id'] = 2
df = df1.append(df2)

table2 = [[1, datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 28), 2, 20],
          [1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1), datetime.datetime(3000, 1, 1), 4, 25],
          [2, datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(3000, 1, 1), 2, 20]]

df3 = pd.DataFrame(table2, columns=['Id', 'Start', 'End', 'Fix', 'Performance'])
```

**edit** In `df3`, the table is grouped on `Id`. I.e. the first two rows are valid for `Id = 1`, and the last for `Id = 2`.

My question is now; is there a way to append `Fix` and `Performance` as columns to `df` such that the elements of the respective columns are on the rows where `Start` and `End` are valid, as determined by `Date`? Which means that my table would look like

```
         Date  Id  Fix  Performance
0  2015-01-01   1   2       20   
1  2015-01-27   1   2       20
2  2015-01-31   1   2       20
3  2015-02-01   1   2       20
4  2015-02-03   1   2       20
5  2015-02-15   1   2       20
6  2015-02-28   1   2       20
7  2015-03-01   1   4       25
8  2015-03-17   1   4       25
9  2015-03-28   1   4       25
10 2015-04-12   1   4       25
11 2015-04-28   1   4       25
0  2015-01-01   2   2       20
1  2015-01-27   2   2       20
2  2015-01-31   2   2       20
3  2015-02-01   2   2       20
4  2015-02-03   2   2       20
5  2015-02-15   2   2       20
6  2015-02-28   2   2       20
7  2015-03-01   2   2       20
8  2015-03-17   2   2       20
9  2015-03-28   2   2       20
10 2015-04-12   2   2       20
11 2015-04-28   2   2       20
```

Thanks, Tingis

Comment: how do you choose Fix and Performance when the date falls in two intervals defined by rows in df3? (for example take data 2001-01-01, line 1 and 3 match)

Comment: Hmm, not quite sure I follow your question. But `Start` in `df3` marks where the date that `Fix` and `Performance` are valid, and `End` in `df3` marks the last date that they are valid. Hope this answers your question!

Comment: @Tingiskhan the three `[Start, End]` intervals in `df3` are overlapping, there is an ambiguity.

Comment: No :) For example I take 2001-01-01. This date falls in interval 1900-01-01 to 2015-02-28 on line 1 of df3 but also on interval 1900-01-01 to 3000-01-01 on line 3 of df3. For these two lines, there are two pairs of Fix/Performance. Which one to choose?

Comment: @galath, exactly ! so either there is an issue on the data, either there must be a rule to take into account this. I wonder what the OP wants!

Comment: Ah, sorry - my question wasn't clear enough. If you look at the left-most column of `df3` you'll see that they are grouped on `Id`. So, the two first rows are for `Id = 1`, wheras the last is for `Id = 2`. I'll add this in the question.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel - hope the above comment clears up your questions!

Comment: my fault I did not noticed this !

Comment: Easy thing to miss, I should have specified this in the question

Comment: Ok, hope the below helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach where you `apply` a function row by row to generate the two wanted columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def search(x):
    df_  = df3[df3.Id==x['Id']]
    mask = np.logical_and(df_.Start<=x['Date'], df_.End>=x['Date'])
    return pd.Series([df_.loc[mask].Fix.tolist()[0], df_.loc[mask].Performance.tolist()[0]])

df[['Fix','Performance']] = df.apply(search, axis=1)

In [423]: df
Out[423]:
         Date  Id  Fix  Performance
0  2015-01-01   1    2           20
1  2015-01-27   1    2           20
2  2015-01-31   1    2           20
3  2015-02-01   1    2           20
4  2015-02-03   1    2           20
5  2015-02-15   1    2           20
6  2015-02-28   1    2           20
7  2015-03-01   1    4           25
8  2015-03-17   1    4           25
9  2015-03-28   1    4           25
10 2015-04-12   1    4           25
11 2015-04-28   1    4           25
0  2015-01-01   2    2           20
1  2015-01-27   2    2           20
2  2015-01-31   2    2           20
3  2015-02-01   2    2           20
4  2015-02-03   2    2           20
5  2015-02-15   2    2           20
6  2015-02-28   2    2           20
7  2015-03-01   2    2           20
8  2015-03-17   2    2           20
9  2015-03-28   2    2           20
10 2015-04-12   2    2           20
11 2015-04-28   2    2           20
```

Comment: Thanks @ColonelBeauvel! This was something that I was looking for in the beginning!

Answer (score 1):

You can first do a SQL-style `outer merge` and then remove those inconsistent records with `Date` falling out of `Start-to-End` Interval.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

# your data
# ========================================================
table = [[datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 27), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 31), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 1), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 3), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 15), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 28), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 17), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 28), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 12), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 28), 1]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Date', 'Id'])
df2 = df1.copy()
df2['Id'] = 2
df = df1.append(df2)

print(df)


         Date  Id
0  2015-01-01   1
1  2015-01-27   1
2  2015-01-31   1
3  2015-02-01   1
4  2015-02-03   1
5  2015-02-15   1
6  2015-02-28   1
7  2015-03-01   1
..        ...  ..
4  2015-02-03   2
5  2015-02-15   2
6  2015-02-28   2
7  2015-03-01   2
8  2015-03-17   2
9  2015-03-28   2
10 2015-04-12   2
11 2015-04-28   2



table2 = [[1, datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 28), 2, 20],
          [1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1), datetime.datetime(2030, 1, 1), 4, 25],
          [2, datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(2030, 1, 1), 2, 20]]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(table2, columns=['Id', 'Start', 'End', 'Fix', 'Performance'])

print(df3)

   Id      Start        End  Fix  Performance
0   1 1900-01-01 2015-02-28    2           20
1   1 2015-03-01 2030-01-01    4           25
2   2 1900-01-01 2030-01-01    2           20


# processing
# =============================================
df_temp = pd.merge(df, df3, on='Id', how='outer')
result = df_temp[(df_temp.Date >= df_temp.Start) & (df_temp.Date <= df_temp.End)].reset_index(drop=True)

         Date  Id      Start        End  Fix  Performance
0  2015-01-01   1 1900-01-01 2015-02-28    2           20
1  2015-01-27   1 1900-01-01 2015-02-28    2           20
2  2015-01-31   1 1900-01-01 2015-02-28    2           20
3  2015-02-01   1 1900-01-01 2015-02-28    2           20
4  2015-02-03   1 1900-01-01 2015-02-28    2           20
5  2015-02-15   1 1900-01-01 2015-02-28    2           20
6  2015-02-28   1 1900-01-01 2015-02-28    2           20
7  2015-03-01   1 2015-03-01 2030-01-01    4           25
8  2015-03-17   1 2015-03-01 2030-01-01    4           25
9  2015-03-28   1 2015-03-01 2030-01-01    4           25
10 2015-04-12   1 2015-03-01 2030-01-01    4           25
11 2015-04-28   1 2015-03-01 2030-01-01    4           25
12 2015-01-01   2 1900-01-01 2030-01-01    2           20
13 2015-01-27   2 1900-01-01 2030-01-01    2           20
14 2015-01-31   2 1900-01-01 2030-01-01    2           20
15 2015-02-01   2 1900-01-01 2030-01-01    2           20
16 2015-02-03   2 1900-01-01 2030-01-01    2           20
17 2015-02-15   2 1900-01-01 2030-01-01    2           20
18 2015-02-28   2 1900-01-01 2030-01-01    2           20
19 2015-03-01   2 1900-01-01 2030-01-01    2           20
20 2015-03-17   2 1900-01-01 2030-01-01    2           20
21 2015-03-28   2 1900-01-01 2030-01-01    2           20
22 2015-04-12   2 1900-01-01 2030-01-01    2           20
23 2015-04-28   2 1900-01-01 2030-01-01    2           20

# if you don't like Start and End columns in the final table, just drop them
result.drop(['Start', 'End'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @JianxunLi! Never occured to me to use the outer merge.

Comment: However, it seems as though I cannot use years greater than 3,000. So, I'll go with Colonel's answer this time! But thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @Tingiskhan No problem at all. :-) The issue with year greater than 3,000 is that pandas convert datetime to `numpy.datetime64` at nanoseconds frequency, and when using 64-bit `int` to store this info, its range is between  1970 and 2262. See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-units for details. To fix it, you could try convert to type to `datetime64` with second frequency.

Comment: Woah, that figures! Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when merging with intervals, a combination of `reindex` and `ffill` has performance that is orders of magnitude better than solutions using `apply` and `outer merge`.

This might not the most elegant solution, but sometimes using either `apply` or `outer merge` are prohibitively slow or consumes too much space. In that case (and I think this makes most of the cases), `reindex` and `ffill` works well, but you need to change your "intervals" table with start and end dates to a sort of "events" table with the starting date from which the new values must be applied:

```
import pandas as pd, datetime

table = [[datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 27), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 31), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 1), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 3), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 15), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 28), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 17), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 28), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 12), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 28), 1]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Date', 'Id'])
df2 = df1.copy()
df2['Id'] = 2
df = df1.append(df2).reset_index()

table3 = [[1, datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1), 2, 20],
          [1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1), 4, 25],
          [2, datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1), 2, 20]]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(table3, columns=['Id', 'Start', 'Fix', 'Performance'])
df3 = df3.set_index(['Id', 'Start'])

df_index = df.set_index(['Id', 'Date']).index
df3 = df3.reindex(df3.index.union(df_index))
df3 = df3.sort_index(level=[0, 1]).ffill().reindex(df_index).astype(int)
df[['Fix','Performance']] = df3.reset_index(drop=True)
```