# Merge 2 pandas dataframes conditional by upper bound (float) and lower bound (float) and merge_asof by date

Tags: python, pandas

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31513207/complicated-merge-based-on-start-and-end-date-pandas), it looks similar to my problem but I tried every solutions in that post and it cannot solve my problem due to different data type (e.g. earlier post has lower bound and upper bound as date but mine are float) and the way to merge (the earlier post use outer merge to get exacy match while my problem need merge_asof with backward direction).  Let me explain my problem again.  I have a sample dataframe as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2022-04-10", "2022-04-11", "2022-04-12", "2022-04-13"],
                   "occupancy": [30, 55, 28, 100]})
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

so my dataframe look like this

```
index   date           occupancy
    0   2022-04-10      30
    1   2022-04-11      55
    2   2022-04-12      28
    3   2022-04-13     100
```

There is another dataframe that represents predefined rules as follows.

```
rules = pd.DataFrame({"lower": [0, 25, 50, 75, 25],
                      "upper": [25, 50, 75, 100, 50],
                      "action": [-15, -5, 20, 25, -10],
                      "filedate": ["2022-04-01", "2022-04-01", "2022-04-01", "2022-04-01", "2022-04-12"]})
rules["filedate"] = pd.to_datetime(rules["filedate"])
```

The rules look like this.

```
index   lower       upper      action         filedate
    0       0          25         -15         2022-04-01
    1      25          50          -5         2022-04-01
    2      50          75          20         2022-04-01
    3      75         100          25         2022-04-01
    4      25          50         -10         2022-04-12
```

I would like to take the `action` column and add it to the `df`.  Merging conditions are, `lower <= occupancy < upper` and `filedate <= date` but the rule is selected based on the nearest filedate that is less than date.  The expected output should be the following.

```
index   date           occupancy  action
    0   2022-04-10      30            -5
    1   2022-04-11      55            20
    2   2022-04-12      28           -10
    3   2022-04-13     100           NaN
```

Explanations of the above output are the following.  For example, row index 0 of `df`, its `occupancy` lies between `lower` (25) and `upper` (50).  There are 2 rows in the `rules` those satisfy such a condition (row index 1 and index row 4).  However, action of row index 1 will be selected because the filedate `2022-04-01` is less than the date `2022-04-10` according to the condition `filedate <= date`.  We can think that the `filedate` is an effective date to execute action.

Another example, row index 2 of `df`, its `occupancy` lies between `lower` (25) and `upper` (50).  There are 2 rows in the `rules` those satisfy such a condition (row index 1 and index row 4) but the action of row index 4 will be selected because the filedate `2022-04-12` is less than or equal to the date `2022-04-12` according to the condition `filedate <= date` but the rule is selected based on the nearest filedate that is less than date.

I think my problem need to use `merge_asof` but I could not figure out how to effectively implement it.  May I have your suggestions?

Comment: For row 2, there are two rows that match your conditions. Rules at index 1 and 4 both have `lower <= occupancy <= upper` and `filedate <= date`. For row 3, rule #4 satisfies your condition. Why do you have `NaN`?

Comment: @not_speshal condition is `lower <= occupancy < upper`.  That's why.

Comment: What about row 2? Why do you choose rule 4 and not 1? Both satisfy your conditions.

Comment: @not_speshal For row 2, rule 4 was selected because of `filedate <= date` but I didn't mention clearly that we will pick the nearest date.  Thank you for this question.  I have editted the post according to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a custom function to do the filtering and `apply` it to each row of your DataFrame:

```
def custom_merge(row):
    sample = rules[rules["lower"].le(row.at["occupancy"])&rules["upper"].gt(row.at["occupancy"])&rules["filedate"].le(row.at["date"])]
    if sample.shape[0] > 0:
        action = sample.loc[sample["filedate"].sub(row["date"]).abs().idxmin()]["action"]
    else:
        action = np.nan
    return action

df["action"] = df.apply(custom_merge, axis=1)

>>> df
        date  occupancy  action
0 2022-04-10         30    -5.0
1 2022-04-11         55    20.0
2 2022-04-12         28   -10.0
3 2022-04-13        100     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I can solve my problem now.  It is not an efficient way but at least the problem solved.  If there is the better way in term of efficiency, please advise.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2022-04-10", "2022-04-11", "2022-04-12", "2022-04-13"],
                       "occupancy": [30, 55, 28, 100]})
    df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
    
    rules = pd.DataFrame({"lower": [0, 25, 50, 75, 25],
                          "upper": [25, 50, 75, 100, 50],
                          "action": [-15, -5, 20, 25, -10],
                          "filedate": ["2022-04-01", "2022-04-01", "2022-04-01", "2022-04-01", "2022-04-12"]})
    rules["filedate"] = pd.to_datetime(rules["filedate"])
    
    
    
    actions = []
    for i in df.index:
        date = df.loc[i, "date"]
        occ = df.loc[i, "occupancy"]
        x = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[i, :]).T
        subrules = rules[rules["filedate"] <= date]
        mask = np.logical_and(subrules["lower"] <= occ, subrules["upper"] > occ)
        temp = subrules[mask.values]
        if temp.empty:
            actions.append(np.nan)
        else:
            actions.append(pd.merge_asof(x, temp, left_on="date", right_on="filedate", direction="backward")["action"].values[0])
    df["action"] = actions
```